# Simplifying Logical Equivalences with Exclusive-OR (XOR)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, propositional-calculus

We were recently introduced to the Rules of Logical Equivalences and we were given examples on how to simplify propositions using RLE. Some of them have exclusive-or (XOR) instead of inclusive-or (OR) and we weren't taught how to deal with it. **How do you apply the rules to XOR?**

Let's say I want to simplify

```
NOT(p AND r) XOR (p OR q)
```

what do I do with the XOR? Another example, I'm having a hard time with is

```
NOT(q XOR p)
```

Initially, I thought I should just replace the XOR with OR but it feels wrong.

Refer to this photo for the RLE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikq0I.png

Comment: Indeed, replacing XOR with OR is incorrect. Note that $p$ XOR $q$ is logically equivalent to $(\neg p \land q) \lor (p \land \neg q)$ or $(p \lor q) \land \neg (p \land q)$. It means that $p$ or $q$ is true, but not both. You can replace the XOR with any logically equivalent formula that is using only the logical connectives that you know.